# Como desplazar automáticamente botón apenas me muestre el alert

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estoy teniendo problemas al desplazar un botón automáticamente apenas se muestra un `alert` de validación, actualmente tengo un input en donde se ingresa un correo y se valida que la cadena que se ingresa corresponda a los caracteres de un correo, la vista para este input esta de esta manera actualmente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si se fijan entre el input y el botón enviar existe un espacio que es necesario para mostrar el `alert` al momento de ingresar correos como no validos, de esta manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quisiera que inicialmente mi botón de enviar y el `input` se ubicaran de esta manera, uno debajo del otro sin el espacio:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero entonces que al momento de mostrar el `alert` correspondiente se desplace automáticamente debajo de el.

Anexo el código de mi input con su botón y la validación, seria de mucha de ayuda.

```js
function EnviarInformacion() {
 var Contacto = $("#Contacto").val();
    const alerta = document.getElementById("alert");
    if (/^(([^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@(([^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+\.)+[^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]{2,})$/i.test(Contacto)) {
    //Codigo de validacion aquí
    } else {
        alerta.classList.add("show")
        }
        }
```

```css
.alert {
    padding: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.alert-danger {
    color: #a94442;
    background-color: #f2dede;
    border-color: #ebccd1;
}

.alert {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row">
                                <div class=" col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                                    <br /><br />
                                    <p>
                                        <span class="ContenidoContactoMensaje">
                                            Ingresa tu correo<br />
                                        </span>
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                                <br />

                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 alinearDerecha">
                                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 row2">

                                        <input type="text" name="Contacto" value="" size="50" class="form-control" id="Contacto" />
                                        <div id="alert" class="alert alert-danger" style="font-family: 'Lettera Text Std';">Favor de ingresar una cuenta de correo válida.</div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 row2">
                                        <button class="EnviarContactoDetalleProducto btn-lg" onclick="EnviarInformacion()"> Enviar</button>
                                    </div>
                                    <br />
                                </div>

                            </div>
```

Comment: Simplemente añadiéndole `display: none;` a `.alert` y a `.show` `display: block;`

Comment: @Daniel intente lo de tu comentario se desplaza el botón pero ahora ya no me muestra el `alert`

Comment: pero agregaste `.show` con el valor de `display: block;` en tu `css`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con un par de cambios puedes lograr lo que buscas:

1. En la clase original cambia la propiedad `transition` para aplicar a todo (opacidad, altura, color, etc.) y asigna `max-height` en cero para que no aparezca un espacio vacío
2. En la clase `show`, pon la opacidad en 1 y `max-height` en un valor que sea suficiente para mostrar completo el elemento. Si crees que puede tener más de 50px de altura, entonces asigna un número mayor, teniendo en cuenta que si este valor es mucho mayor a la altura real la transición podría no verse bien.

Bootstrap tiene reglas declaradas para la clase `.alert`, por lo que hay que ser más específicos para tener los cambios esperados, eliminando margen inferior y dejando solo un espacio pequeño de separación entre mensaje y botón

```js
function EnviarInformacion() {
 var Contacto = $("#Contacto").val();
    const alerta = document.getElementById("alert");
    // Eliminar clase antes de validar
    alerta.classList.remove("show")
    if (/^(([^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@(([^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+\.)+[^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]{2,})$/i.test(Contacto)) {
        //Codigo de validacion aquí
    } else {
        // Agregar clase cuando es un correo inválido
        alerta.classList.add("show")
    }
}
```

```css
.alert {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    max-height:0; /* Comienza con altura en cero */
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
.alert-danger {
    color: #a94442;
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: #f2dede;
    border-color: #ebccd1;
}
#alert {
    margin-bottom: 10px; /* Ajusta a tu gusto para separar el botón */
    padding: 0;  /* No ocupar espacio al estar oculto */
}
.show {
    opacity: 1;
    max-height: 50px; /* Altura adaptable a contenido */
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row">
                                <div class=" col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                                    <br /><br />
                                    <p>
                                        <span class="ContenidoContactoMensaje">
                                            Ingresa tu correo<br />
                                        </span>
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                                <br />

                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 alinearDerecha">
                                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 row2">

                                        <input type="text" name="Contacto" value="" size="50" class="form-control" id="Contacto" />
                                        <div id="alert" class="alert alert-danger" style="font-family: 'Lettera Text Std';">Favor de ingresar una cuenta de correo válida.</div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 row2">
                                        <button class="EnviarContactoDetalleProducto btn-lg" onclick="EnviarInformacion()"> Enviar</button>
                                    </div>
                                    <br />
                                </div>

                            </div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, ya va tomando un poco mas de forma el `alert` al momento de mostrarse pero tengo una duda, hay manera de que el botón Enviar quede mas cerca al `input ` algo así como el ejemplo de mi pregunta?

Comment: @JohnDoe, listo, solo agregué una regla para `#alert`, donde puedes ajustar el espacio entre _input_ y botón.